# NSUserdefault not saving value ios9.3 , ios 10 , using side navigation

Tags: objective-c, ios9, nsuserdefaults

This issue has been cause of lots of frustration , as NSUserDefaults stopped working.
i am saving facebook information in userdefaults for later use , but it is returning nil.
 Note : i get nil when i try to slide in side navigation (using SWRevealViewController) bar.

here is my code :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[RespArray valueForKey:@"image_url"]] forKey:@"profilePic"];
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

What i have tried :
- add/remove synchronize
- clearing all NSUserDefaults from app
- using setObject , SetValue for NSUserDefault key
- using NSString Stringwithformat , for retrieving strings.

i tried each and every solution available on SO and web.

Comment: Is `[RespArray valueForKey:@"image_url"]` nil? Are you facing an async issue? When you do `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  objectForKey:@"profilePic"]`, what do you have exactly?

Comment: 1) There is no need to call `synchronize`. 2) Don't use `setValue:forKey:`, use `setObject:forKey:`.